# Buffer overflow exploit not working for kernel module

Tags: kernel-module, buffer-overflow, exploit

I have done buffer overflow exploits for user level processes in the past. However this does not seem to work good if I try to overflow the buffer of a vulnerable kernel module. Here's what I do:

There is a vulnerable kernel module which I can open as a file and read/write to it. The write operation is done without bounds checking. So I do a write operation and overflow the buffer and overwrite the return address as the address of an environment variable that has my shellcode. But something is going wrong. The kernel crashes and after rebooting I opened /var/log/messages and find that the eip is correctly pointing to the address I overwrote. But still it crashes saying "Unable to handle kernel null pointer dereference at virtual address"
Any reason why this would happen? Why wouldn't the control be redirected to a overwritten return address?

Note: I ran this on redhat enterprise linux with exec-shield and ASLR turned off.

Comment: Might be more appropriate on security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @bstpierre Was not aware of it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel can't jump to user addresses without performing a kernel exit, since it is running in a privileged mode with a different configuration than userspace (e.g. different paging tables, CPU permission bits, etc.).

So, in order to get shellcode into the kernel, you'd have to pack the shellcode into the buffer written to the driver (and copied to the kernel), and somehow get the address of it. This is not so hard if you have access to the kernel map, but recently Linux distributions have begun locking access to such sensitive information to make it harder to exploit kernel bugs.